# jQuery .val() method is triggering a change event in IE8

Tags: jquery

I have a select that has a change event on it, which shows a confirm box.  If the user clicks 'cancel', then i change the value back to what it was before (with .val()).  However, in IE8 this is triggering a change event again, restarting the cycle.

There must be a cleaner way to set the select back to it's previous value, without triggering another change event, but i can't think of it :/  Any suggestions?  Here's what i'm doing right now, which may well be rather clumsy:

```
  $("#quiz_style").change(function(){
    var selected = $(this).val(); 
    if(selected == "classic"){
      if (!confirm("confirmation message for changing to classic")) {
          $(this).val('sequential');
          return false;
      }      
    } else if(selected == "sequential"){
      if (!confirm("confirmation message for changing to sequential")) {
          $(this).val('classic');
          return false;
      }       
    }
  });
```

EDIT - bit more info.  My original post was a bit misleading, as it said that the use of val() triggers another change event.  That's not quite true i think: what happens is that the select is changed back, with nothing untoward happening, but then when i click elsewhere on the page (anywhere) the change event is triggered again.

Comment: Setting a value like that does **not** trigger a "change" event in any browser. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/zZamx/) is your code in a jsfiddle and it works fine in IE8.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to jsfiddle pointy, that's a great resource.  I can't replicate my problem there either, even with my exact source html and js (which is slightly bigger than in my post) - i put that up at http://jsfiddle.net/toastkid/NtgbE/.  See my OP for an edit with some more details of the problem, which might cast some light.  Cheers, max

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't do that, and it doesn't seem to: http://jsbin.com/omewa6 Tested in IE8 (and IE6, and Chrome, and Firefox, and Opera...). You'll want to look elsewhere in your code for the problem, although I can't immediately think what it would be if that code is what you're actually using...